# 'fplot' cannot accept hidden parameters

Tags: matlab

These codes are wrong:

```
syms bt;    
f=415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664
            fplot(@(bt) f,[0.01 1],'b')
```

But these codes are right:

```
syms bt;   
fplot(@(bt) 415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664,[0.01 1],'b')
```

Are they not same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are different. For the first code:

```
f=415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664
fplot(@(bt) f,[0.01 1],'b')
```

f do not know what is bt. In this way, error happen. In the second code:

```
fplot(@(bt) 415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664,[0.01 1],'b'
```

the bt has been denoted as the independent variable.

If you want to use the first code, you can code as:

```
f=@(bt)(415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664)
fplot(@(bt) f(bt),[0.01 1],'b')
```

In this way, the bt has been denoted as independent variable.

Comment: I edited my question, so I denoted syms bt. In this case, why the first is wrong?

Comment: In the code fplot(@(bt)f), bt means nothing for f. Do you know how to use the @(x)?For example, f = @(x)(x+1), you can use f(1) to get the result. But in @(bt)f, I don't know how to understand it. By the way, if you really like to use this kind of code, @Adam provide the correct code.

Comment: Thank you , but I still don't know how to use @.

Comment: @(bt) f(bt)` is the same as `f`. `f` already is a function handle, and can be used in `plot` where a handle is expected. There's no point in creating an anonymous function that only calls another function with the same arguments.

Answer (score 4):

```
syms bt;    
f=415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664
fplot(@(bt) f,[0.01 1],'b')
```

The syntax is completely wrong here.

Pass `bt` to the function `f` as argument, with `syms` function just use `subs`

```
@(bt) f   --------> @(bt) subs(f)
```

```
syms bt;    
f=415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664
fplot(@(bt) subs(f),[0.01 1],'b')
```

**Correct syntax:**

- Since `f` is already a function why defining a `new function handle`
  to duplicate an existing function?
- With `fplot()` you can use directly `syms` function

```
syms bt;    
f=415136356873531/(2251799813685248*bt) + 703048105211593/70368744177664
fplot(f,[0.01 1],'b')
```

Comment: I added '@(bt)' because I saw fplot function:fplot(@(x) sin(x)). I always think '@' can not be deleted.